# Error - "Invalid Input Detected" when uploading to phpmotion

Tags: php, html, upload

I have installed the phpmotion script to my website details follow:

I have uploaded the requested files in binary and rest in ASCII as it told me too
The phpmotion is installed to www.mysite.com/videos and all relevant changes have been made
The CGI bin directory and all sub files are Chmod 755

I cant seem to find the answer anywhere!

So when im uploading a video it gets to 100% then on a white page the only thing that displays is:

Error - Invalid Input Detected

Thats all it gives me =( any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Since the code isn't downloadable without registering for a forum, can you search the source code for that error message and post some of the relevant code around it?  If you find the message, it may shed some light onto what the cause of the problem is.

Comment: Hey @drew010, thanks for the response, i tried this however the file is a .pl and i havent a clue about it! Parts look like php and others dont. Its very odd, i tried before to search for the error but it didnt exist :-/ i contacted my web host it may be the perl script isnt running on their server.

Comment: Ok, hopefully they can help you get it resolved, maybe it is some server configuration rather than the script.  Good luck.